# No feedback PHP and AJAX "POST"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

after I click a button, there are no respond at all at the page.

I use post method to get the variable in the ajax file. Here are the code.

the **original.php** is the file that contain the form that get value, and sent it to the ajax file.

**stockProcess.php** is the ajax file that run a sql process to update the stock in the database.

**original.php**

```
<div id='status'></div>

<input type='number' name='quantity' style='max-width:50px' id='quantity'/>

<button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' onClick='add('pen100')'>
    <i class='ace-icon fa fa-plus bigger-120'></i>
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function add(serialNo)
{
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    var type = "add";

    if (quantity == null)
    {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<p><b><font color='red'>PLEASE INPUT A VALUE</font></b></p>";
    }
    else if (quantity < 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<p><b><font color='red'>WRONG VALUE<br />PLEASE ENTER VALUE LARGER THAN 0</font></b></p>";
    }
    else
    { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            {
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST","stockProcess.php?serialNo="+serialNo+"&quantity="+quantity+"&type="+type, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

**stockProcess.php**

```
<?php

$serialNo = $_POST['serialNo'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$type = $_POST['type'];

if ($type == "add")
    {
        $newQ = $quantity + 50;
        $sqlAdd = "UPDATE medicinestock SET quantity=$newQ WHERE serialNo='$serialNo'";
        $queryAdd = $conn -> query($sqlAdd);

        if ($queryAdd == TRUE)
        {
            echo "<b><p><font color='green'>STOCK HAS BEEN UPDATE</font></p></b>";
        }
        else
        {
            $err = $conn -> error;
            echo "<b><p><font color='red'>SYSTEM ERROR : $err</font></p></b>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: insted of simple ajax you can use jQuery ajax..!!

Comment: what if i want to use this method instead? which part i should fix?

Comment: you have an idea about jQuery ?

Comment: @SoniVimal Why the insistence on using jQuery? The OP has tagged it with javascript, so it makes sense to use that instead of having to include another library

Comment: @asprin, What is JQuery ? you know ?

Comment: @SoniVimal Yes, I'm well aware of what jQuery is. What I'm stating is that you don't need to use it when the job can also be done via native javascript. Why the unnecessary overhead?

Comment: @asprin, its okay you were right :) leave it , I did whatever I found right

Comment: @SoniVimal - i know jQuery. Im still learning, so step by step.

Comment: @asyraf , maybe my answer is useful to you ... please check you need to add basic jQuery laibrary file in head tag and then you can use my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in this line :

```
<button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' onClick='add('pen100')'>
```

Just change below code:

**`onClick="add('pen100')"`**

Comment: @Asyraf , i have tested locally (getting error on console with your script) , but when i do as i suggest then request is going properly.

Comment: if i do like this should be ok right?

<button class='btn btn-xs btn-success' onClick="add('RM <?php echo $price; ?>')">
               <i class='ace-icon fa fa-plus bigger-120'></i>
              </button>

Answer (score 0):

When using `POST` you have to send your data in request body by passing in it as parameter to `send()`.Also set the `Content-type` and other headers

```
var payLoad = "serialNo="+serialNo+"&quantity="+quantity+"&type="+type;

xmlhttp.open("POST","stockProcess.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //mandatory header
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", payLoad.length); //recommended headers
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(payLoad); //send
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually use AJAX native for un-refresh-able form POST and I'm not to skillfull on AJAX thing. I just trying to use it.

Actually i chasing the due date to finish the project, so just change it to normal form POST.

for the code is

original.php

```
<form method="POST" action="stockProcess.php">
//Button and Input number will be write here.
</form>
```

Sory for all the trouble. ^_^

Answer (score -1):

Try This code:

```
    <div id='status'></div>
    <input type='number' name='quantity' style='max-width:50px' id='quantity'/>
    <button class='btn btn-xs btn-success ajaxBtn' data-param-serialNo="pen100">
        <i class='ace-icon fa fa-plus bigger-120'></i>
    </button>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("button.ajaxBtn").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var serialNo = $(this).attr('data-param-serialNo');
      var quantity = $('input[name="quantity"]').val();
      var type = "add";

      if(quantity == null){
        $('div#status').append("<p><b><font color='red'>PLEASE INPUT A VALUE</font></b></p>");
      }else if(quantity < 0){
        $('div#status').append("<p><b><font color='red'>WRONG VALUE<br />PLEASE ENTER VALUE LARGER THAN 0</font></b></p>");
      }else{
        $data = "serialNo="+serialNo+"&quantity="+quantity+"&type="+type;
        $.ajax({
          url: "stockProcess.php",
          data: $data,
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
            $("#status").append(data);
          }
        });
      }
    });
})
    </script>
```

Comment: do i need to put the script in jQuery(function($) ?